# CCDS Data Source Script will not log string

Tags: javascript, workday-api

I have a script that runs when I click a "Test Connection" button in an Adaptive Insights Integration script.  I am trying to log the XML that is returned, just to verify the information prior to coding the next part.  The script I have is as follows:

```
function testConnection(context) {
    // dataSource variable to get Data Source Setting Parameters
    var dataSource = context.getDataSource();
    
    // Get the static credentials parameters.
    const userName = dataSource.getSetting("Adaptive Username").getValue(); // Not Nedeed after WD User Sync. Do Not delete 
    const password = dataSource.getSetting("Adaptive Password").getValue(); // Not Nedeed after WD User Sync. Do Not delete 
    const instanceCode = dataSource.getSetting("instanceCode").getValue();
    
    //This example connects to Postman Echo using POST
    var url = 'https://api.adaptiveinsights.com/api/v35';
    var method = 'POST';
    
    // XML request body, this is where the method type (ie. exportUsers) goes.
    var body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><call method="exportUsers" callerName="AdaptiveInsightsAPI">'
    body += '<credentials login="' + userName + '" password="' + password + '" /></call>';
    
    var headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml' };
    
    var response = null;
    let finalResponse = null;
    
    try {
        response = ai.https.request(url, method, body, headers);
        finalResponse = response.getBody();
        ai.log.logVerbose("API Call Successful", finalResponse);
        return true;
    }
    catch (exception) {
        ai.log.logInfo('api call failed', '' + exception);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The response will not show in the log, it only shows "...".  However, if I change "finalResponse" to "finalResponse[1]" or try to log any other character from the string ([2],[3],[4],etc.), it displays the character in the string.  I also tried to slice the characters to fit within the 1000 character limit, but that displays nothing at all when I try to log the response.

What can I do different to get the response body into the log?